# DELETE V1/addresses/:addressId - This Rest API is not working with Customer Token

Tags: magento-2.1.7, rest-api

```
delete /V1/addresses/{addressId}
```

This is the Delete Address REST API in Magento 2.

It works with admin tokens, but not with customer tokens.

I think it should be working with custom tokens as customers should have the right to delete their own addresses stored.

This API has access permission for Resource: **Magento_Customer::manage**

This resource permission should be working with customer token, isn't it?

Does anybody have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Customer token CANNOT access `customerAddressRepositoryV1` so your API doesn't work on customer token. This is how swagger looks after inserting a customer token:
[image]

If customer wants to modify/delete customer address, we can use `PUT /V1/customer/me`. Although it doesn't list on swagger(Confirmed: [it's a bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10099)), it tested and successful on my 2.1.7 EE + POSTMAN. Here is a sample JSON for using `PUT /V1/customer/me`:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "email": "your_email",
    "firstname": "your_firstname",
    "lastname": "your_lastname",
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [

    ],
    ...
   }
}
```

Of course, you have to add token on header.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.. I found that if there is a resource Magento_Customer::manage applied on webapi.xml , it indicates that we need to use admin token. And if Magento_Customer::customer resource is applied in any API, we can use customer token.

Comment: So i needed to use admin token. But I think my question can be considered as an enhancement for magento team. as customer should have rights to delete his own address with customer token.

Thanks again...

Comment: Yes I think it should be an enhancement on it. BTW if my workaround works please accept my answer :)