# Add new customer address REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Is there is an API to add new customer address without admin token?

Comment: You can look at my previous answer in another question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189570/42656

Comment: Thanks, But this works for update Address only, He can't add another new address. what i want to do is enable customer to add new addresses for shipping and billing addresses.

Comment: You can. Just fill in the "address" field is OK

Comment: Firstly, I added one address, then added another one in new call. It removed the old one and have only one address. Secondly, I added two addresses on one call, then added another new one in second call, It removed the all addresses and have the last one address only in my address book. !

Comment: So you need to keep the address if you intend to keep it

Comment: Yes, I want to keep it. but how?

Comment: Just use `GET /V1/customer/me` to get all customer info

Comment: No, it will return only the addresses saved in your book address

Comment: So just copy the return JSON and put it onto `PUT /V1/customer/me`

Comment: But is this logic ?? this will cause two requests and post all addresses again .

Comment: Of course, why not? It's the worst method before Magento side release the address API to customer.

Comment: MMM, How can i do it as a custom (if could) ?

Comment: hi @Jsparo30 do u have any idea how to use PUT /V1/customer/me ?

Answer (score 2):

@jsparo30 We have only one default shipping address and one default billing address, when you hit api first it sets to default shipping/billing address because you send a parameter

> "default_shipping": true ,
>
> "default_billing": true,

When you call it second time , i think you forget to make it false, that's why it deleted you previous address.